# Bootloader Screen HD/OS Selection

Tags: bootloader

Installed Ubuntu 12.04.  Computer has 3 HDs partitioned and multiple instances of Windows XP. HD configuration as follows:

```
SDA Vista|Ubuntu;  SDB  Windows XP (1);  SDC Windows XP (2) | Windows XP (3)
```

**Boot Screen looks as follows:**

```
  Ubuntu,with Linux 3.2.0-52-generic-pae
  Ubuntu,with Linux 3.2.0-52-generic-pae  (recovery mode)
  Previous Linux versions
  Memory test  (memtest86+)
  Memory test  (memtest86+,serial console 115200)
  Windows Vista (loader)  (on /dev/sda3)
  Microsoft Windows XP Professional  (on /dev/sdb1)
  Microsoft Windows XP Professional  (on /dev/sdc1)
  Microsoft Windows XP Professional  (on /dev/sdc2)
```

If Windows XP (!) is selected, the computer boot correctly on the instance of XP on HD SDB.  However if Windows XP (2) or (3) is selected, the computer still boots on the instance of XP on HD SDB vice SDC.

Looking at file /boot/grub/grub.cfg for SDB, and SDC:

```
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sdb1)" --class windows --class os { 
    insmod part_msdos 
    insmod ntfs 
    set root='(hd1,msdos1)' 
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F6ECD6C9ECD68373 
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} 
    chainloader +1 
} 
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sdc1)" --class windows --class os { 
    insmod part_msdos 
    insmod ntfs 
    set root='(hd2,msdos1)' 
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F6ECD6C9ECD68373 
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} 
    chainloader +1 
} 
menuentry "Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sdc2)" --class windows --class os { 
    insmod part_msdos 
    insmod ntfs 
    set root='(hd2,msdos2)' 
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F6ECD6C9ECD68373 
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root} 
    chainloader +1
```

It appears that the 3 partitions/instances of Windows XP have the same UUID which may be the problem.  How can this be fixed?  If the UUID can be change, will this change the ability the selected the partition to be booted using the computer's BIOS Boot Menu (F2) or (F12)?

Comment: So running `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu does not fix the problem and detect each instance of XP?

Comment: The problem is not fixed by running sudo update-grub.  Duplicate UUIDs still exist.  I have read an article about changing the UUID in a linux forum but I have not been able to determine what is the impact on Windows.  Since I still use both I do not want to mess up either.

Comment: Are they they same because you did image copy of original install? Then boot.ini would also refer to the same install.

Comment: That is exactly it.  The instances were create from an image of the first XP install and then modified for use with a sprecific set of programs.  I normally control booting with F2 or F12.  As far as the SDC, I control the partition to be boot thru a Disk Director program to mark the wanted partition to active.  So it appears that before modifying Grub.cfg I need to assighn new UUIDs to SDC1 & SDC2.  But will that action infer with Windows booting when I do not boot thru Grub on SDA that is using F12 to boot on SDC (Disk 5 on my system)?

Answer (score 0):

To point Grub to the correct UUIDs, discover the correct ones with `sudo blkid` and then replace them in `grub.cfg`.